# Two linked auto updating(according to input in the other) number input fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have these 2 number input fields from a HTML form.

```
<div class="orderinput">
    <label>         
        Number of pages:
        <input type="number" id="pagecount" onchange="calculatecost();convertPages()" value="1" />
        or words:
        <input type="number" id="wordcount" onchange="convertWords"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

What i need to do is to create a javascript function that converts pagecount to wordcount and updates the wordcount field onchange if the user keys in the pagecount and also converts wordcount to pagecount and updates the pagecount field onchange if the user keys in the wordcount. This snippet from my .js file i currently have only updates wordcount field when the pagecount is keyed in but does not update the pagecount when the wordcount is keyed in.

```
function convertPages(){
    var pgs = document.forms["ordercalc"].elements["pagecount"].value;
    var wrds = pgs * 275;
    document.forms["ordercalc"].elements["wordcount"].value = wrds ;}
function convertWords(){
    var wrds = document.forms["ordercalc"].elements["wordcount"].value;
    var pgs = wrds * 0.0036;
    document.forms["ordercalc"].elements["pagecount"].value = pgs ;
}
```

I would like to do it in one function but i do not know how. Please note 1 unit in pagecount field == 275 units in wordcount field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one function that is called in both onchanges, but there's a problem. The following 4 lines are from your 2 functions. Depending on the order of them you'll get different values IMHO. So you'll need to know whether the pages or the words value was changed, and adjust the other. But then you're back with the 2 functions or if/else statement.

```
    //pgs = p.value;
    //wrds = pgs * 275;
    //
    //wrds = w.value;
    //pgs = wrds * 0.0036;
```

If you want to know which DOM element was changed you can use `event.target` for it. You could differentiate between them by looking at `event.target.id` for example.

```js
    function convertBoth(el){
        var p = document.getElementById("pagecount"); // OK
        var w = document.getElementById("wordcount"); // OK
        var pgs, wrds;

        if (el.id == "pagecount") {
          pgs = p.value;
          wrds = pgs * 275;
        } else {
          wrds = w.value;
          pgs = wrds * 0.0036;
        }
    
        w.value = wrds; // OK
        p.value = pgs; // OK
    }
```

```html
<div class="orderinput">
    <label>         
        Number of pages:
        <input type="number" id="pagecount" onchange="convertBoth(this)" value="1" />
        or words:
        <input type="number" id="wordcount" onchange="convertBoth(this)"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be better to use `pgs = wrds / 275;` and eliminate the rounding error?

Comment: @Rycochet, anyway you'll calculate with doubles, I don't see a difference, though your version is more readable maybe. But you should've ask Kakali about it, that comes from his code

Comment: I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined` on the line: `if (event.target.id == "pagecount") {`. Is something wrong?

Comment: @Rycochet yeah. Will use `... /275`.

Comment: @Gavriel Thanks Alot!